# Why does my simple belongsTo ralationship in Laravel not working?

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-8

I have a users migration as follows:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And a BlogPosts migration as follows:

```
 Schema::create('blog_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->string('image');
            $table->text('text');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

They each have a Model (BlogPost and User)

On BlogPost Model i have the following:

```
public function getUser(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

I have added some testdata to the DB as follows:

user table:

> ID: 1, email: test@test.com, password: hashed

blog_post table:

> ID: 1, title: title, image: /image.jpg, text: some text, user_id: 1

Now in tinker I do the following:

```
$var = \App\Models\BlogPost::find(1);
$var->getUser(); //Outputs: null
```

If I modify getUser to:

```
public function getUser(){
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->toSql();
        }
```

The output from tinker is:

> select * from `users` where `users`.`id` is null

What am I doing wrong here?, am I missing something?

Comment: Have you added `user_id` value in your  `blog_post` table row?

Comment: Yea sorry, was a typo. I have corrected it

Comment: try add this to your blog posts migration, and remove `->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();`
`$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');`

Comment: `$var->getUser`, or `$var->getUser()->first()`. You might be better off if you name your relationship `user`, so you can do `$var->user` or `$var->user()->first()`. As a sidenote, when you use `()`, it's a query until you call `->first()`, then it's a Model instance or `null`. If you don't use `()`, `->first()` is automatically called behind the scenes.

Comment: @MiqayelSrapionyan that gives the same result :(

Comment: @user2192013 Have you update your db? like `php artisan migrate:fresh` with my code?

Comment: @TimLewis, thank you for clearing that up. Now its working :) Will you add an answer or should I?

Comment: @MiqayelSrapionyan yes I did. I also have an database seeder I run, giving me more data then provided here. It does the exact same thing as when I use "->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();" unfortunately

Comment: actually we need to tell belongsTo that user_id is foreign key. i checked that myself. it worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, when you call the relationship with `()`, you have an instance of the `Builder` class, which allows you to chain methods to perform additional query logic. For example:

```
$var = BlogPost::find(1);
$var->getUser();
```

If you run this code in `php artisan tinker`, the output shouldn't be `null`, but rather an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo`. It's expected that you pass a `closure` to your query to actually execute it:

```
$var = BlogPost::find(1);
$var->getUser()->first();
```

This should output an instance of `App\Models\User`, or, if there are no associated records, `null`.

Relationships provide a quick-access property as well, allowing you to simply do:

```
$var = BlogPost::find(1);
$var->getUser;
```

When you omit the `()`, the appropriate `closure` is automatically applied behind the scenes. In the case of a `belongsTo()`, `->first()` is applied.

Finally, it's recommended to name your relationship after the Model it's associated to. In this case:

```
public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

For a couple reasons. First, `public function getUser()` suggests calling via a getter method (like you're doing, via `->getUser()`), but since this can be called as a property (via `->getUser`), it's ambiguous. Secondly, using the same name as the Model applies the foreign key automatically. Compare:

```
public function getUser() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

public function user() {
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

If you use `getUser()`, you need to pass `user_id` as the foreign key (cheers to r89human for catching this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66441903/3965631). If you use `user()`, then it's automatically determined.

Comment: this is a great detailed reply. thanks for that.

Comment: No problem! Good catch on the `user_id` param; I added that to my answer, but gave you credit as well :) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

use this code and it will work fine.

```
public function getUser() {
        return $this->belongsTo( User::class, 'user_id' );
}
```

we need to tell belongsTo method that user_id is foreign key.